# require()'ing a CoffeeScript file from a JavaScript file or REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm using Node.js and wanting to incorporate CoffeeScript into my workflow. I have two use-cases:

1. I want to be able to write JavaScript files which `require()` CoffeeScript modules
2. I want to be able to load CoffeeScript modules from within the node REPL

**For case #1:** I can just compile from `.coffee` to `.js` and `require()` the `.js` module, as a workaround.

**For case #2:** Right now I'm `eval()`ing the output of `coffee-script.compile()`.

Is there a better, more unified way to do this?

Comment: What about the CoffeeScript REPL, `coffee`?

Comment: That REPL is very primitive compared to the node one: it lacks colour, autocompletion, multi-line statements etc

Comment: Update: the `coffee` REPL is now awesome :)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The *coffee-script* module registers its extension once required.

```
$ echo 'console.log "works"' > module.coffee

$ echo '
> require("coffee-script")
> require("./module")
> ' > test.js

$ node test.js
works

$ node
> require('coffee-script'); require('./module')
works
{}
```

**Edit**: This behaviour has changed with the relase of CoffeeScript 1.7.0. Now you need to do:

```
require('coffee-script/register');
```

Comment: Huh, why didn't I think of that? :)

Comment: `require.extensions` is now deprecated and there is no alternative yet.

Comment: I expect it to stick around as it's a stable feature and, as you mentioned, there are not alternatives yet.

Answer (score 12):

A more versatile solution would be to use [better-require](https://github.com/olalonde/better-require).

```
npm install better-require
```

It lets you `require()` CoffeeScript files, no pre-compilation needed. (It also lets you `require()` a bunch of other file formats: CoffeeScript, clojurescript, yaml, xml, etc.)

In the case of CoffeeScript, it simply requires the `coffee-script` module.

```
require('better-require')();
var myModule = require('./mymodule.coffee');
var clojurescriptModule = require('./mymodule.cljs');
// etc.
```

**Disclosure:** I wrote `better-require`.

Comment: the central problem with `require.extensions`—that registering an extension changes global state, for your entire application—is, sadly, not addressed by `better-require`, meaning that things will break if any of your 3rd party sub-modules happen to depend upon a different version of, say, Yaml, or CoffeeScript.

Comment: better-require also doesn't load ".litcoffee" modules by default, whereas they can be loaded via `require('coffee-script/register');`