# Can I mix JS and CoffeeScript in a project?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I'm using `ExpressJS` and the `app.js` is straight JavaScript. If I wanted to use CoffeeScript, would I have to rewrite app.js or can I just write my additional files with `CoffeeScript`?

Comment: As long as you 'compile' it to JS, then you should be ok. CoffeeScript is just a way to write JS in ruby-style.

Comment: So I need to compile before running node.js? Is there anyway to automate it via express?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you talking about using CoffeeScript on the server side, or serving it as compiled JavaScript to the client? Either way, it's pretty easy.

You can load `.coffee` files with `require`, as long as your application has loaded the `coffee-script` library first. So just start your app with

```
require 'coffee-script'
```

(after installing it with npm, of course) and from that point on, any time you write

```
require 'foo'
```

from any part of your app, it'll look for both `foo.js` and `foo.coffee`. (Obviously the converse is true that a `.coffee` file can `require` a `.js` file; from Node's perspective, the `.coffee` file is just JavaScript.)

As for serving CoffeeScript as JS to the client from Express, I suggest taking a look at my [connect-assets](http://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets) middleware.

Answer (score 5):

As of Coffeescript 1.7.0 you need to

```
require('coffee-script/register');
```

vs the mentioned

```
require('coffee-script');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `require("coffee-script")` from a .js file, you can then subsequently `require("some-module")` where some-module is written in CoffeeScript and it will 'just work' without a manual compilation step required.

See this question: [require()'ing a CoffeeScript file from a JavaScript file or REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768748/requireing-a-coffeescript-file-from-a-javascript-file-or-repl)