# Requiring CoffeeScript file from within another CoffeeScript file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I was wondering if you are able to require a coffeescript from within another coffeescript.

My example code from file "user.coffee"

```
class UserObj
    constructor: (@name) ->
        console.log @name
```

My example code from main file

```
require "./user.coffee"

User = new UserObj "Example"
```

Is this possible from within a coffeescript file or just a js file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [require()'ing a CoffeeScript file from a JavaScript file or REPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768748/requireing-a-coffeescript-file-from-a-javascript-file-or-repl)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible.

user.coffee:

```
exports.UserObj = 
class UserObj
    constructor: (@name) ->
        console.log @name
```

main.coffee:

```
{UserObj} = require "./user"

User = new UserObj "Example"
```

Comment: But this is just for Node right? I thought CoffeeScript may have pull together the required files on compilation of main.js

Comment: @ThomasWelton That's just for Node. Currently CoffeeScript compiler is just a file-to-file transcompiler, it doesn't do any project structure analysis and because of that no aggregation. There may be [other tools](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Build-tools) approaching the issue. I even remember [writing one myself](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/Robusta).

Comment: Thanks. I later went on to use requirejs which I'm very happy with for loading coffeescript modules and classes.

Comment: If you are using a single class per file, then I would prefer `module.exports = UserObj`, now the prototype is exposed out of the file, and the `{UserObj} = require './user'` isn't necessary. The loading of the constructor would simply be: `UserObj = require './user'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [coffee-stir](http://bit.ly/1j8emop) to include other dependencies. Its a way around only using required from the web and it will add dependencies as you use it. 
FYI i made the lib when i was facing similar problems