# How can I require a CoffeeScript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/syntax/code_reuse_on_client_and_server) for CoffeScript.

I open the terminal, navigate to the directory where `simpleMath.coffee` is present and run `node` and try `var SimpleMath = require('./simpleMath');`, which results in the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'simpleMath'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:18
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I tried `simpleMath` as well, without `./`.

Comment: Have you looked at the NodeJS docs, see http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: of course you need to compile your coffee to js before you can use it in NODE.js ;-)

Comment: try to start the `coffee` repl instead of `node`

Comment: possible duplicate of [require()'ing a CoffeeScript file from a JavaScript file or REPL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768748/requireing-a-coffeescript-file-from-a-javascript-file-or-repl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile your coffeee into js first. See https://github.com/oklai/koala it catches and compile your files in a GUI - and send notifications when it fails. Really good.