# Requiring CoffeeScript from Node.js application gives cannot find module error

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to require a CoffeeScript file from a Node.js application but Node.js gives error `Error: Cannot find module 'something'`. What is the proper way to do this? If I compile the CoffeeScript code beforehand, it works but I don't want to do this.

test.js:

```
require('coffee-script').register();

require('something');
```

something.coffee:

```
console.log('Hello World!');
```

Console output:

```
> node test.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'something'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\smallscale\test.js:3:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: You're also against a watch process that compiles it?

Comment: @DaveNewton Well I found multiple answers suggesting this should be possible. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/4769079/2193958.

Comment: Why not try what it said there? I always have a watcher that's linting and compiling so I don't really know about on-demand compilation--sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to `require()` a file using the structure to `require()` a module.

If you `require()` something without giving `require()` a path to a file (absolute or relative), Node.js is going to look up for your module inside the `/node_modules` directory. You can read the documentation [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).

Try requiring your module as a JavaScript file like this:

```
require('./something')
```

(and make sure `'./something'` is the path from where you require the module to where the module is located in your app structure, or use an absolute path).